# Pytest changes the behaviour of a generator recursive function

Tags: python-3.x, pytest

This is my code:
where 'schema' and 'config' are heavily nested dictionaries, this function work as intended when run separately.

```
def find_config_difference(schema, config, key_name=None):
    for k in schema:
        try:
            if "default" in schema[k] and k in config:
                if schema[k]["default"] != config[k]:
                    out_of_date_default.append(f"key {k} in {key_name} has out of date default value.")
                schema[k] = schema[k]["default"]
        except TypeError:
            pass
        finally:
            if k in config:
                if isinstance((schema[k] and config[k]), dict):
                    find_config_difference(schema[k], config[k], key_name=k)
            else:
                yield f"{k} in {key_name} is missing/extra in config"

output = list(find_config_difference(schema, config))
```

This is my pytest code :
when run through pytest it does not call the function recursively and 'for' loop only goes through the outermost keys of 'schema'.

```
import unittest
from unittest.mock import patch
from config_compare import *
import ast

config = ast.literal_eval(open('config.json', 'r').read())
schema = ast.literal_eval(open('config_schema.json', 'r').read())


class Test_config_compare(unittest.TestCase):


    def test_find_config_difference(self):
        missing = list(find_config_difference(schema, config, key_name=None))
        length = len(missing)
        print(length)
```

Here is a section of 'schema', which is almost similar to 'config'.
it would only iterate through keys($schema, additionalProperties, definitions, button_content)

```
schema = {
    "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-07/schema#",
    "additionalProperties": false,
    "definitions": {
        "color_hex": {"pattern": "^#([A-Fa-f0-9]{6})$", "type": "string"},
        "palette": {
            "additionalProperties": false,
            "properties": {
                "background": {"$ref": "#/definitions/color_hex", "default": "#FFFFFF"},
                "primary": {
                    "rules": {"testTR": 12, "tier": 2},
                },
            },
        },
    },
    "button_content": {
        "additionalProperties": false,
        "properties": {
            "accessibilityLabel": {"type": "string"},
        },
        "required": ["accessibilityLabel", "value"],
        "type": "object",
    },
}
```

When I removed the yield generator it works fine. But, I also don't want to remove it and store the string in a variable. So is there a way to work around it?

Comment: Please give a [mre] with example inputs. Also why are you using literal_eval on a JSON file? Either it's not really JSON or you'll get errors on true, false, null.

Comment: It is a json file. 
json.loads(open('config.json', 'r').read()) loads it as a string.

Comment: No it doesn't. And load (rather than loads, where the s is for string) handles files directly.

Answer (score 1):

Your recursive function cannot possibly work. It's a generator function, but when you make the recursive call, you're not iterating over the returned generator object. You probably want to `yield from` the recursive call:

```
    finally:
        if k in config:
            if isinstance((schema[k] and config[k]), dict):
                yield from find_config_difference(schema[k], config[k], key_name=k)
```

If you want to be selective about which values yielded by the recursion get yielded, you could write your own `for` loop iterating on the recursive result with whatever logic you want in it, yielding or not as you desire.

All that said, the fact that your function is both a generator that yields values, *and* it has side effects (such as updating `out_of_date_default` and some of the `schema[k]` values) seems like a dubious design. You should probably make your function *only* do one of those things (either modify things in place, or yield new values, not both).